# Potential bug when sorting facet rows/columns

Tags: json, charts, visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have a facet chart with both rows and columns. I want to sort both rows and columns by largest values from left to right and top to bottom (top left is the largest). This works fine when we have data for every row and column but if some data is missing then the values get pushed up into the wrong row or column as you can see below.

Is this a bug?

I managed to get around this by pushing in fake values with a JavaScript function but just wanted to check what was going wrong here. Hover over each box and you will see Japan has been shifted up into Europe now.

```
{
  "data": {"url": "data/cars.json"},
  "mark": "bar",
  "transform": [
    {
      "filter": "datum.Origin === 'Japan' || datum.Origin === 'Europe'"
    },
    {
      "filter": "datum.Horsepower >= 110"
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [{"op": "count", "field": "Name", "as": "CountOrigin"}],
      "groupby": ["Origin"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "slice('000000' + format(datum.CountOrigin, '.0f'), -6) + '-' + datum.Origin",
      "as": "OriginSort"
    },
    {
      "joinaggregate": [
        {"op": "count", "field": "Name", "as": "CountCylinders"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["Cylinders"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "slice('000000' + format(datum.CountCylinders, '.0f'), -6) + '-' + format(datum.Cylinders, '.0f')",
      "as": "CylindersSort"
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "field": "Name", "type": "quantitative"},
    "row": {
      "field": "Origin",
      "type": "nominal",
      "sort": {"field": "OriginSort", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "column": {
      "field": "Cylinders",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "sort": {"field": "CylindersSort", "order": "descending"}
    },
    "tooltip": [
      {"field": "Name"},
      {"field": "Origin"},
      {"field": "OriginSort"},
      {"field": "CylindersSort"}
    ],
    "color": {"field": "Horsepower", "type": "ordinal"}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug. See here for more background: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/8675

Comment: Thanks Davide. That's a shame. Maybe @jakevdp has a solution?
If you need my JavaScript fix then just let me know.,

Comment: Could be worth adding to the reported issue so the devs know it is still a problem.

Comment: I will add a comment on github.